# How to join multiple occurrences of record against master record with filter

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table which shows a big library of products.

I have several filters which can be applied to the table via Kendo Grid, but the problem I am having only concerns MySQL.

I have a date range filter, which needs to filter the list of products by when they were sold.

The issue I am having is that because a product could have sold more than once, it causes the product lines to duplicate, because their are for example four "dateSold" rows to one product. I know why this is, but I can't figure out how to do the syntax for my filter:

```
SELECT ...
FROM parts_library
LEFT JOIN parts_sale_dates AS PSD ON PSD.partLibId = parts_library.id
```

When applying a date filter it would look something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM parts_library
LEFT JOIN parts_sale_dates AS PSD ON PSD.partLibId = parts_library.id
WHERE PSD.dateSold >= ?
```

Another issue is that by doing:

```
SELECT ...
FROM parts_library
LEFT JOIN parts_sale_dates AS PSD ON PSD.partLibId = parts_library.id
```

Makes the query take donkeys because there are about 500,000 products.

Comment: what indexes do you have

Comment: @DrewPierce Parts_sale_dates is a memory table and has indexes on partLibId and the primary key is id. Think it would be better to switch to a normal table or not?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal The date filter is what I am not sure about. A product could have been sold 0 or more times. The date filter would check to see if the date of the sale fell within the range specified by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like "between":

```
SELECT ...
FROM parts_library pl LEFT JOIN
     parts_sale_dates psd
     ON PSD.partLibId = pl.id
WHERE PSD.dateSold between <DATE1> and <DATE2>;
```

If you want *just* the parts with no duplicates, you can express this as:

```
SELECT distinct pl.*
FROM parts_library pl LEFT JOIN
     parts_sale_dates psd
     ON PSD.partLibId = pl.id
WHERE PSD.dateSold between <DATE1> and <DATE2>;
```

The performance on large data sets will not be, shall I say, good.

The following is equivalent, but it should have better performance:

```
select pl.*
from parts_library pl
where exists (select 1
              from parts_sales_dates psd
              where psd.partLibId = pl.id and
                    psd.dateSold between <DATE1> and <DATE2>
             )
```

You can improve the performance by having an index on `parts_sales_dates(partsLibId, dateSold)`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that has it bringing back the results I want but the performance is horrendous when it tries to bring back a lot of results :(

Comment: @imperium2335 . . . If you have 500,000 products, you probably have a very large tables.  Investigate strategies like partitioning the data and be sure that your MySQL options are set to optimize the use of available hardware.